# Laravell @yield is converting quotes to html entities

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, html-entities

Upgraded a Laravel 5.3 site to Laravel 8 (php8). Everything works except for a little snippet:

```
window.appModules =  [@yield("app-modules" , "'main'")] ;
```

This is now rendering with html entities for the quotes, like so:

```
window.appModules = [&#039;main&#039;, &#039;behavior&#039;]
```

for the behavior page. This elicits a syntax error: Unexpected token '&'

I have tried every way I can think of to escape this or decode, in html, php and javascript but have yet to find something that handles it. Mind you, this worked fine in Laravel 5.3 (PHP 5.6). Any idea what I can do to keep the quotes from being converted to htmlentities or otherwise resolve this. Near as I can tell the pages would still work fine even with the html entities, except for the syntax error that is being generated.

Comment: Don't include the quotes in the values. If you can show some more of the template and the included template it might help explain things better. Generally speaking though, you shouldn't be outputting JS data with yield, instead use variables and `@json` directive.

Comment: It's not something I created. This syntax worked under Laravel 5.3 but not 8. Here is the who'e script syntax:

Comment: <script id="shared-data" type="text/javascript">
            window.appModules = [@yield("app-modules", "'main'")];
            @stack("head-script")
        </script>

Comment: PHP 8.1 has changed the default behavior of htmlspecialchars and htmlentities functions ( https://php.watch/versions/8.1/html-entity-default-value-changes )